# Remove the _@_ insert pop-up button on Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

Is there a way to hide/remove the *@* insert pop-up button that appears in every new line in Google Documents?
(So that every time you press Enter writing your essay you get just plain old clear line, not an annoying button.)

Tried creating general rules in Adguard browser app, like ##docs-instant-bubble. Doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 1):

As found in https://www.reddit.com/r/googledocs/comments/198e8sm/remove_the_symbol_dropdown_menu/, I put the line

docs.google.com###docs-instant-bubble

in Brave browser / settings / shields / create custom filters
and after reloading any Google Doc, the @ no longer appears.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Firefox with the uBlock origin extension. Simply add it to the My Filters as a new line, apply changes, and refresh the Google Doc tab.